# Linking Azure VM size with its family

Tags: powershell, azure

I'm trying to check the core availability before deploying a new server using powershell.

I managed to get the current core limit and values per vCPU family but the VM sizes don't have their "families" listed.

Is there any way to do this efficiently?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to do this efficiently?

For now, there is **no** Azure PowerShell command to list Azure VM size and it's VCPU family.

As we know, we can use this command `Get-AzureRmVMUsage` to get the limit:

```
PS C:\Users\Jason> Get-AzureRmVMUsage -Location eastus

Name                             Current Value Limit  Unit
----                             ------------- -----  ----
Availability Sets                            0  2000 Count
Total Regional vCPUs                         0    20 Count
Virtual Machines                             0 10000 Count
Virtual Machine Scale Sets                   0  2000 Count
Basic A Family vCPUs                         0    20 Count
Standard A0-A7 Family vCPUs                  0    20 Count
Standard A8-A11 Family vCPUs                 0    20 Count
Standard D Family vCPUs                      0    20 Count
Standard Dv2 Family vCPUs                    0    20 Count
Standard G Family vCPUs                      0    20 Count
Standard DS Family vCPUs                     0    20 Count
Standard DSv2 Family vCPUs                   0    20 Count
Standard GS Family vCPUs                     0    20 Count
Standard F Family vCPUs                      0    20 Count
Standard FS Family vCPUs                     0    20 Count
Standard NV Family vCPUs                     0    18 Count
Standard NC Family vCPUs                     0    18 Count
Standard H Family vCPUs                      0     8 Count
Standard Av2 Family vCPUs                    0    20 Count
Standard LS Family vCPUs                     0    20 Count
Standard Dv2 Promo Family vCPUs              0    20 Count
Standard DSv2 Promo Family vCPUs             0    20 Count
Standard MS Family vCPUs                     0     0 Count
Standard Dv3 Family vCPUs                    0    20 Count
Standard DSv3 Family vCPUs                   0    20 Count
Standard Ev3 Family vCPUs                    0    20 Count
Standard ESv3 Family vCPUs                   0    20 Count
Standard B Family vCPUs                      0    10 Count
Standard FSv2 Family vCPUs                   0    20 Count
Standard ND Family vCPUs                     0     0 Count
Standard NCv2 Family vCPUs                   0     0 Count
Standard NCv3 Family vCPUs                   0     0 Count
Standard LSv2 Family vCPUs                   0     0 Count
Standard Storage Managed Disks               0 10000 Count
Premium Storage Managed Disks                0 10000 Count
```

We can use this command `Get-AzureRmVMSize` to get the details about Azure VM size:

[image]

We can use Azure VM size name to find the size family.

**Note**:

If a quota increase is required to either purchase a Single Subscription RI, you can [request a quota increase](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/resource-manager-core-quotas-request) on your subscription.

Comment: If it helps, please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it as an answer so that other community members will be benefited, thanks:)

Comment: Does that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

you can build your own map with regex. something like this:

```perl
foreach ($location in @('EastUS')) {
  Get-AzVmSize -Location $location | % {
    New-Object -TypeName PSobject -Property @{
      Name                 = $_.Name;
      NumberOfCores        = $_.NumberOfCores;
      MemoryInMB           = $_.MemoryInMB;
      MaxDataDiskCount     = $_.MaxDataDiskCount;
      OSDiskSizeInMB       = $_.OSDiskSizeInMB;
      ResourceDiskSizeInMB = $_.ResourceDiskSizeInMB;
      Family               = $(switch -regex ($_.Name) {
        '^(Basic|Standard)_(A|B|D|E|F|H|L|M)[0-9]+m?r?$' {
          '{0} {1} Family vCPUs' -f $matches[1], $matches[2];
          break;
        }
        '^(Basic|Standard)_(A|B|D|E|F|H|L|M)[0-9]+m?r?_Promo$' {
          '{0} {1} Promo Family vCPUs' -f $matches[1], $matches[2];
          break;
        }
        '^(Basic|Standard)_(A|B|D|E|F|H|L|M)[0-9]+[lmt]?s$' {
          '{0} {1}S Family vCPUs' -f $matches[1], $matches[2];
          break;
        }
        '^(Basic|Standard)_(A|B|D|E|F|H|L|M|P)([BC])[0-9]+r?s$' {
          '{0} {1}{2}S Family vCPUs' -f $matches[1], $matches[2], $matches[3];
          break;
        }
        '^(Basic|Standard)_(A|B|D|E|F|H|L|M)[0-9]+(-(1|2|4|8|16|32|64))?m?s$' {
          '{0} {1}S Family vCPUs' -f $matches[1], $matches[2];
          break;
        }
        '^(Basic|Standard)_(A|B|D|E|F|H|L|M)S[0-9]+$' {
          '{0} {1}S Family vCPUs' -f $matches[1], $matches[2];
          break;
        }
        '^(Basic|Standard)_(A|B|D|E|F|H|L|M)1?[0-9]+m?_v([2-4])$' {
          '{0} {1}v{2} Family vCPUs' -f $matches[1], $matches[2], $matches[3];
          break;
        }
        '^(Basic|Standard)_(A|B|D|E|F|H|L|M)?[0-9]+_v([2-4])_Promo$' {
          '{0} {1}v{2} Promo Family vCPUs' -f $matches[1], $matches[2], $matches[3];
          break;
        }
        '^(Basic|Standard)_(A|B|D|E|F|H|L|M)1?[0-9]+_v([2-4])$' {
          '{0} {1}v{2} Family vCPUs' -f $matches[1], $matches[2], $matches[3];
          break;
        }
        '^(Basic|Standard)_(A|B|D|E|F|H|L|M)1?[0-9]+m?s_v([2-4])$' {
          '{0} {1}Sv{2} Family vCPUs' -f $matches[1], $matches[2], $matches[3];
          break;
        }
        '^(Basic|Standard)_(A|B|D|E|F|H|L|M)[0-9]+(-(1|2|4|8|16|32|64))?s_v([2-4])$' {
          '{0} {1}Sv{2} Family vCPUs' -f $matches[1], $matches[2], $matches[5];
          break;
        }
        '^(Basic|Standard)_(A|B|D|E|F|H|L|M)S[0-9]+(-(1|2|4|8|16|32|64))?_v([2-4])$' {
          '{0} {1}Sv{2} Family vCPUs' -f $matches[1], $matches[2], $matches[5];
          break;
        }
        '^(Basic|Standard)_(A|B|D|E|F|H|L|M)[0-9]+(-(1|2|4|8|16|32|64))?i_v([2-4])$' {
          '{0} {1}Iv{2} Family vCPUs' -f $matches[1], $matches[2], $matches[5];
          break;
        }
        '^(Basic|Standard)_(A|B|D|E|F|H|L|M)[0-9]+(-(1|2|4|8|16|32|64))?is_v([2-4])$' {
          '{0} {1}ISv{2} Family vCPUs' -f $matches[1], $matches[2], $matches[5];
          break;
        }
        '^(Basic|Standard)_(A|B|D|E|F|H|L|M)S[0-9]+_v([2-4])_Promo$' {
          '{0} {1}Sv{2} Promo Family vCPUs' -f $matches[1], $matches[2], $matches[3];
          break;
        }
        '^(Basic|Standard)_(A|B|D|E|F|H|L|M)1?[0-9]+a_v([2-4])$' {
          '{0} {1}Av{2} Family vCPUs' -f $matches[1], $matches[2], $matches[3];
          break;
        }
        '^(Basic|Standard)_(A|B|D|E|F|H|L|M)1?[0-9]+as_v([2-4])$' {
          '{0} {1}ASv{2} Family vCPUs' -f $matches[1], $matches[2], $matches[3];
          break;
        }
        '^Standard_N([CV])[0-9]+r?$' {
          'Standard N{0} Family vCPUs' -f $matches[1];
          break;
        }
        '^Standard_N([CV])[0-9]+r?_Promo$' {
          'Standard N{0} Promo Family vCPUs' -f $matches[1];
          break;
        }
        '^Standard_N([DP])S[0-9]+$' {
          'Standard N{0}S Family vCPUs' -f $matches[1];
          break;
        }
        '^Standard_N([DP])[0-9]+r?s$' {
          'Standard N{0}S Family vCPUs' -f $matches[1];
          break;
        }
        '^Standard_N([CDV])[0-9]+r?s_v([2-4])$' {
          'Standard N{0}Sv{1} Family vCPUs' -f $matches[1], $matches[2];
          break;
        }
        default {
          $null;
          break;
        }
      })
    }
  } | Format-Table
}
```